# Spring write to UTF-8 response encoding issues

Tags: java, spring, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to write Word doc (as an XML ) to the response using Spring 4

I set the setContentType to be utf-8 response,

The source  xml is encoded in UTF-8

But some of the UTF-8 characters are getting as gibberish 

What am I doing wrong?

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params="action=downloadDocument" )
 public @ResponseBody void getDocumentForStudent(@RequestParam("student_id")String student_id,
                                            HttpServletResponse response) {     
    try {

        response.setContentType("application/msword;charset=utf-8");  
        response.setHeader("Content-encoding","UTF-8");  
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Document" + student_id +".doc");  

       // document path here 

       InputStream is = new FileInputStream(document);
       BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       String buf = null;

       PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
        Set<String> keySet = replaceTokens.keySet();
        while ((buf = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
            for (String key : keySet) {                 
                buf  = buf.replace(key, tokens.get(key));
            }

           output.print(buf);
        }

       response.flushBuffer();
       rdr.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
         logger.error("Error writing file to output stream. ", ex);
         throw new RuntimeException("IO Error reading or writing file to output stream!",ex);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give a try with the below

```
out.write(buf.getBytes("UTF-8"));  or   out.write(new String(buf, "UTF-8"));
```

and also change while reading the file -

```
((new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: this did the trick thank you!
        CODE:                      
 BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(studentDoc), "UTF8"));

Comment: @user648026 If you want to know why: that is because if you do not specify the character encoding, it will use the default character encoding of your system, which is apparently not UTF-8.